# Use of float command when language changes in css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an issue that when language changes the all elements changes direction from `ltr` to `rtl` and float command also changed from left to right direction.
is there any way that `ltr` changes but float stay right?
please view images below

[when float left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i2SD.jpg)

[when float right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM6kN.jpg)

the original language is English which is set as dir="ltr" but Arabic set as "rtl" and these elements appear as rtl when floated in Arabic, so how can I fix it?

```css
.flip-clock-divider {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  height: 50px;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<div id="ab__deal_of_the_day_141" class="flip-clock-wrapper">
  <span class="flip-clock-divider days"><span class="flip-clock-label">days</span></span>
  <ul class="flip ">
    <li class="flip-clock-before">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">2</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flip-clock-active">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">3</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="flip ">
    <li class="flip-clock-before">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">7</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">7</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flip-clock-active">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">8</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="flip-clock-divider hours"><span class="flip-clock-label">hours</span><span class="flip-clock-dot top"></span><span class="flip-clock-dot bottom"></span></span>
  <ul class="flip ">
    <li class="flip-clock-before">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">1</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flip-clock-active">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">1</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="flip  play">
    <li class="flip-clock-before">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">5</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flip-clock-active">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">4</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="flip-clock-divider minutes"><span class="flip-clock-label">minutes</span><span class="flip-clock-dot top"></span><span class="flip-clock-dot bottom"></span></span>
  <ul class="flip  play">
    <li class="flip-clock-before">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">1</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flip-clock-active">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">0</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="flip  play">
    <li class="flip-clock-before">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">1</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flip-clock-active">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">0</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="flip-clock-divider seconds"><span class="flip-clock-label">seconds</span><span class="flip-clock-dot top"></span><span class="flip-clock-dot bottom"></span></span>
  <ul class="flip  play">
    <li class="flip-clock-before">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">3</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flip-clock-active">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">2</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="flip  play">
    <li class="flip-clock-before">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">3</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flip-clock-active">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="up">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <div class="inn">2</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</html>
```

is it possible to float it initial?

Comment: Can you put a subset of the HTML and CSS in a JSFiddle or embed a code snippet. The images are not informative enough.

Comment: @Shoppingpak it's working what actually you want.

Comment: If you want this particular content to show as LTR all the time - then you should simply put a `dir` attribute on your `.flip-clock-wrapper` element. (You seem to be under the wrong impression that the direction could only be specified for the root html element, but that is of course not the case.)